# Separate Redis database for testing in Laravel

Tags: testing, laravel-5, redis

I'm using Redis to store user-defined config for my Laravel app. I want to know how can I separate the Redis database is being used while testing from the one that is going to be used in for production? That's because I need to flush Redis before each test case and I don't want this to touch my data in main (production) Redis database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different Redis database. In your `config/database.php`:

```
       'default' => [
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
            ],
        ],
```

You can set a different `REDIS_DB` in your `.env.testing` (e.g. `REDIS_DB=1`)